# Windows Phone with node.js / socket-io. How to start?

Tags: node.js, socket.io, windows-phone

I have some socket-io server on node.js running.
I want to communicate from Windows Phone application to this node.js.

But I have no idea how to start with this. 
I've found SocketIO4NET and it's running fantastic but on console application. I can not move it to Windows Phone unfortenately because there is no WP version of SocketIO4NET assembly.

Does anybody have any idea how to bite it?

Answer (score 0):

One approach to this could be as follows.

Create a phonegap app for the Windows Phone, with socket.io.js included in the app (so that it can send events to the node server). And obviously create a NodeJs server, with socket.io module, which will listen and respond to the events sent from the phonegap app.

This approach could be useful, if you really don't want to stick to a native Windows Phone app.

Refer to this video to get a clue. http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=M5IAlnU96SI